# How to display a tkinter text after pressing a push button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a project and it includes using a push button. After clicking the push button a tkinter text view should appear in my window but for some reason it does not appear. This is the code that I have done in triggering of the push button.

```
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (320,320)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

proc = ImageProcess()
count = -1

while True:
    if not GPIO.input(21):
        camera.capture('/home/pi/Thesis/Test/lets.jpg')
        count += 1
        img = cv2.imread("/home/pi/Thesis/Test/lets.jpg")

        print(proc.frame_table(img))

        pickle_in = open("game_file.pickle","rb")
        example_dict = pickle.load(pickle_in)

        text1 = Text(self, height=30, width=30)
        text1.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='N')

        text2 = Text(self, height=30, width=30)
        text2.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='N')

        text1.insert(tk.INSERT,example_dict[0])
```

After pushing a button it will go to a class where I'll get the strings and store it in a pickle file then load it then put it on the text. The output that I want is after pushing the button and it captures the images the strings that I got will be put in a text widget and repeat until many strings has been put on the text widget.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tk.Button you can pass the argument command `tk.Button(self, text="Save", command=self.onSave`. Make sure you pass the function without "()".

Comment: Im using a push button

Comment: @XiaoSy You forgot to show us that part of the code.